# Inline Ternary Conditional Operator

Tags: reactjs, jsx, ternary

I'm trying to render a component using a ternary operation. I want to show a component if this.state.info and this.state.shortdef have a length greater than 0. What is the correct way to code that and why? Here is my code:

```
render (){

  return (

      <div>
        <div>
        {!(this.state.info && this.state.shortdef.length > 0) ? <addBook /> }
        </div>
      </div>
  );
  }
```

Comment: `{this.state.info && this.state.shortdef.length > 0 && <addBook />}`

Comment: Also as a side note, React components should *always* start with a capital letter. Make it `<AddBook />`

Answer (score 0):

```
{(this.state.info.length > 0 && this.state.shortdef.length > 0 && <addBook />}
```

If you don't have a 2nd option to return you don't need the ternary operator. The && will render the component if the preceding statements are true.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you dont need ternary, you can use `&&` operator, but lil suggestions for your code, components should always start with capital so `<AddBook />` and I would personally move the condition into constant, to make render less bulky.

```
render (){
  const hasNoBooks = !(this.state.info && this.state.shortdef.length > 0)

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        { hasNoBooks && <AddBook /> }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a component on a particular condition go by this:

```
{(this.state.info && this.state.shortdef.length > 0) && <addBook />}
```

If you want to show one component on a particular condition and another when the condition fails, use the `ternary` operator:

```
{(this.state.info && this.state.shortdef.length > 0) ? <addBook /> : <SomeOtherComponent />}
```

Comment: Hi @Rohan, this is very helpful. For some reason the component is not registering even though I have it listed as an import. Is there another reason that it may not register?

Comment: Can you edit the question and paste your code where you are facing this issue.?